# Is there a reason why is the nomenclature of matplotlib different in object-oriented interface?

Tags: python, matplotlib

To the risk of asking a dumb question that will be closed: why are the names of the methods in Matplotlib different between object-oriented mode and the state-machine mode?

For example, I can created a grided axis in two ways:

```
plt.figure()
plt.grid()
# OR
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
```

which makes sense to me. The same goes to include the legends (`plt.legend()` and `ax.legend()`). However, for some specific commands this isn't true. For example the labels:

```
plt.xlabel('x')
# translates to
ax.set_xlabel('x')
```

I know this is a minor issue, but it's always bugged me. Is there a reason why the methods don't have the same name? I feel the documentation doesn't do a good job explaining the difference between the two modes so I can't find anything there.

Comment: Read [this](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#general-concepts) overview. But basically, there is a state-machine interface and a more typical object-oriented interface. The state-machine interface mimics MATLAB's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the matplotlib commands were initially named after MATLAB commands, partly because the pylab API was initially aimed at providing a Python alternative to MATLAB plotting.  As matplotlib evolved, a more consistent naming scheme was developed for the "OO interface", but the MATLAB-esque names have remained.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't see why the OO naming scheme is more consistent. I don't see I single reason why they wouldn't keep the original naming in the OO interface.

Comment: @TomCho: Well, for one thing, in the original scheme, you don't know if `xlabel` gets the current label, sets a new one, or both (depending on arguments).  Having separate methods for `get_xlabel` and `set_xlabel` makes that more clear.

Comment: The setter and getter nomenclature is very common on oo programming. You can get and set any property with `get_<property>` and `set_<property>`. I think it would be more confusing if you had a getter and setter for each and every property in this way, just not for the ticks and label. `grid` and `legend` are no properties, so they can be just the same as the pyplot equivalent.